# Splitting a string into six new variables in r

Tags: r, reshape2

I'm trying to split a string of numbers into six different variables. I tried doing it in the original df, but it caused me a lot of problems, so I decided to extract the column I needed to split into a temporary dataframe (with the intent of just left joining the dataframe back to the original once the variables where correct):

```
statusTemp <- select(recruitDF, Status)

tail(statusTemp, n = 15)
                       Status
486 109 ; 0 ; 0 ; 22 ; 0 ; 7 
487   63 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ; 0 ; 3 
488   93 ; 0 ; 0 ; 4 ; 0 ; 2 
489   42 ; 0 ; 0 ; 3 ; 0 ; 2 
490   13 ; 0 ; 0 ; 5 ; 0 ; 1 
491   50 ; 0 ; 0 ; 1 ; 0 ; 3 
492   10 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ; 0 ; 1 
493   56 ; 0 ; 0 ; 3 ; 0 ; 2 
494   40 ; 0 ; 0 ; 3 ; 0 ; 0 
495  35 ; 0 ; 0 ; 10 ; 0 ; 0 
496  134 ; 0 ; 0 ; 5 ; 0 ; 1 
497   12 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ; 0 ; 1 
498   30 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 
499   49 ; 0 ; 0 ; 6 ; 0 ; 4 
500   11 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0
```

I then tried using the `colsplit` from `reshape2` to split up the temp into six new and appropriate variables, but I mess up somewhere, and I can't figure out why.

```
library(reshape2)
library(stringr)

statusTemp <- colsplit(statusTemp, ";", names = c("Application",
                                                  "Screening",
                                                  "Test",
                                                  "Interview",
                                                  "References",
                                                  "Hired"))

str(statusTemp)
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Application: chr "c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1, 13, 188, 13, 1, 13, 188, 118, 118, 275, 188, 1, 13, 188, 337, 13, 355, 188, 118, 246, 64, 246, 64"| __truncated__
 $ Screening  : logi NA
 $ Test       : logi NA
 $ Interview  : logi NA
 $ References : logi NA
 $ Hired      : logi NA
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm overlooking or doing wrong?

Comment: Btw I have already tried to use `" ; "` in the colsplit, but it gives the same result

Comment: `colsplit(statusTemp$Status, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

statusTemp %>% separate(Status, c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), ";") %>%
mutate_all(funs(str_trim))       # to remove both leading and trailing whitespace
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine. As stated by @Cath, you need to use `statusTemp$Status` instead of `statusTemp`. Here is an exemple.

```
library(reshape2)
colsplit(df$Status, ";", names = c("Application",
                                   "Screening",
                                   "Test",
                                   "Interview",
                                   "References",
                                   "Hired"))
# output
#   Application Screening Test Interview References Hired
#1          109         0    0        22          0     7
#2           63         0    0         2          0     3
#3           93         0    0         4          0     2
#4           42         0    0         3          0     2
#...

# data
structure(list(Status = structure(c(2L, 14L, 15L, 10L, 5L, 12L, 
1L, 13L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 11L, 3L), .Label = c("                        10 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ; 0 ; 1 ", 
"                        109 ; 0 ; 0 ; 22 ; 0 ; 7 ", "                        11 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0", 
"                        12 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ; 0 ; 1 ", "                        13 ; 0 ; 0 ; 5 ; 0 ; 1 ", 
"                        134 ; 0 ; 0 ; 5 ; 0 ; 1 ", "                        30 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ", 
"                        35 ; 0 ; 0 ; 10 ; 0 ; 0 ", "                        40 ; 0 ; 0 ; 3 ; 0 ; 0 ", 
"                        42 ; 0 ; 0 ; 3 ; 0 ; 2 ", "                        49 ; 0 ; 0 ; 6 ; 0 ; 4 ", 
"                        50 ; 0 ; 0 ; 1 ; 0 ; 3 ", "                        56 ; 0 ; 0 ; 3 ; 0 ; 2 ", 
"                        63 ; 0 ; 0 ; 2 ; 0 ; 3 ", "                        93 ; 0 ; 0 ; 4 ; 0 ; 2 "
), class = "factor")), .Names = "Status", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```